# Backing up a Couchbase 2.0 cluster from a non-CB server

Tags: python, backup, couchbase

Couchbase ships with a backup tool called `cbbackup` (the docs are [here](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-backup-restore-backup-cbbackup.html)).

In my setup, I have a cluster of 4 Couchbase nodes (let's call them CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4).

I want to backup my entire cluster (including design docs and all buckets) but I want to run the backup procedure **from my backup server** (let's call it B1).

When I run `cbbackup` (on B1) and point it at CB1, I properly download and save the data from all nodes. However, when attempting to download the design docs, the backup borks.

Looking through the code, I notice that there is a restriction in two places where node filtering is done that limits the returned list to nodes that begin with the host pattern "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" (this is in `pump.py` and `pump_tap.py`).

Tracing back this logic, it seems to me that it is impossible to backup design docs on CB1 from a node other than CB1.

Am I wrong? Is this possible?

If it's not possible (follow-up question) can somebody point me to a design decision that justifies this, or explain the logic behind the decision?

Comment: This is something that should be possible.

I have tested on my environment (Linux/Ubuntu) and it is working. Could you please share with us the command you are using and the log/error message you have?